# How can I instantiate a class using the shorthand C# way?

Tags: c#, class, instantiation

This is the class I'm trying to instantiate:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public class Posicion
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here I'm trying to create it:

```
button1.Tag = new Posicion() { 1, 1 };
```

I remember I used to be able to do something like this before, how can I instantiate an object by giving it values up front in the single line? Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the *object initializer* syntax:

```
button1.Tag = new Posicion() { X = 1, Y = 1 };
```

or even:

```
button1.Tag = new Posicion { X = 1, Y = 1 };
```

This relies on `X` and `Y` having public setters.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I wasn't far off. :D

Comment: What is the difference between using parenthesis or not ?

Comment: The only difference is how it looks to you.  Some people like the parens to remind themselves that they really are constructing an object, others like code as concise as possible.  Functionally, the results are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can do without the empty brackets:

```
button1.Tag = new Posicion { X = 1, Y = 1 };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
button1.Tag = new Posicion() { X = 1, Y = 1 };
```